# Android: Space between image and text inside edit text

Tags: android

As the title said, I want to put a little bit of space between the lock icon and the text.

[image]

And here is my current XML:

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/guide_payment_settings_email_et"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/border_paylpal_blue"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue_rounded_lock"
         android:hint="name@example.com"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:textColor="#4d4e5b"
         android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to add below line on your xml :-

```
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

above line give padding after drawable.